# Is it possible to reference a bean created with @Service from applicationContext?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have the following situation:

appContext.xml: contains DAO mappers beans (UserMapper, RoleMapper...)

appContext-security.xml: contains http tag which needs a reference to one of my services (UserDetailsService)

app-servlet.xml: contains tags to find the annotations

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.example.myapp"/> 
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
```

My services have @Service("serviceName") annotation. That means the beans are created by app-servlet.xml.

OpenID login needs UserDetailsService class to work and UserDetailsService has an autowired field (UserService) This is my appContext-security.xml:

```
<security:http auto-config="true">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/welcome*" access="ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/user/*" access="ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/rest/*" access="ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/admin/*" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />
    <security:logout logout-success-url="/" />
    <security:openid-login default-target-url="/welcome" authentication-failure-url="/loginfailed" user-service-ref="userDetailsService"/>
    <security:form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/welcome" authentication-failure-url="/loginfailed" />  
    <security:access-denied-handler ref="openIdAuthFailureHandler"/>
</security:http>
```

I guess I can't refer to UserDetailsService because it is created by app-servlet.xml and it is a child of the root config files (appContext.xml and appContext-security.xml)

If I try to declare UserDetailsService in appContext-security.xml its autowired field UserService is null in debug:

```
<bean id="userDetailsService" class="com.example.myapp.service.impl.UserDetailsServiceImpl"/>
```

Could it be a solution to split the scan? Maybe, it could be a good idea to scan Services in appContext.xml and scan controllers only in app-servlet but I don't know if it makes sense.

I would like to have UserDetailsService annotated by @Service and get its reference to appContext-security.xml. That's my main question. Can I refer to UserDetailservice created with @Service from appContext-security.xml? And if not... what changes do I need?

Correct answer will be voted.

Edit:

I did the following:

appContext.xml:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.example.myapp">
    <context:exclude-filter type="regex" expression="com\.example\.myapp\.controller..*"/> 
</context:component-scan>
```

app-servlet.xml:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.example.myapp.controller" />

<!-- Enabling Spring MVC configuration through annotations -->
<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

Now it works

Comment: Why do you not scan only the controller the packages in `app-servlet.xml` and the rest of the packages in `appContext.xml`? That would probably solve your problem

Comment: Now I did it. Thanks @geonand

Comment: I will add it as an answer for future readers to easily find. Please accept it if it's not to much trouble in order to help future readers

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is change your component scanning.

In `appContext.xml` (the configuration for the root application context)

```
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.example.myapp">
        <context:exclude-filter type="regex" expression="com\.example\.myapp\.controller..*"/> 
        <!--or use this instead 
        <context:exclude-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller"/> 
        -->
    </context:component-scan>
```

In `app-servlet.xml` (the configuration for the web application context)

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.example.myapp.controller" />
```

That way all beans besides controllers will be present in the root application context, and therefor be accessible in your security code.